# Member function passed as std::function to template, binding all params

Tags: c++, templates

I have started building the permission management library,
the basic idea is that you have some sort of configuration read from a file and based on that you can execute a functional object which will be wrapping "allow" and "restrict" functions.

The code so far is divided into few parts

I have a permission manager which says if given "std::string" is able to be executed or not:

```
class PermissionManager {
    public:
        virtual bool canAccess(std::string resource) {return true;};
};
```

Next, I have the actual wrapper on the function:

```
template <typename FuncT>
class PermissionFunction {
private:
    FuncT m_restrict;
    FuncT m_allow;
    PermissionManager *m_pManager;
    std::string m_resource;

public:
    PermissionFunction(const PermissionFunction&) = delete;
    PermissionFunction& operator=(const PermissionFunction&) = delete;
    PermissionFunction(FuncT r, FuncT a, PermissionManager *man, std::string res)
        : m_restrict(r), m_allow(a), m_pManager(man), m_resource(res){
    }

    template<typename ...ARG>
    typename std::result_of<FuncT(ARG&&...)>::type operator()(ARG&&... args){
        if(m_pManager->canAccess(m_resource)){
            return m_allow(std::forward<ARG>(args)...);
        } else {
            return m_restrict(std::forward<ARG>(args)...);
        }
    }
```

};

So, the usage is something like:

```
PermissionManager tpm{};
std::function<void(int)> testRestrict = [](int a){std::cout << "Restrict" << std::endl;};
std::function<void(int)> testAllow = [](int a){std::cout << "Allow" << std::endl;};
PermissionFunction<decltype(testRestrict)> testPerm(testRestrict, testAllow, &tpm, "hi");
for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
    testPerm(i);
}
```

It works really nice for the non member std::functions, however when I want to define it with a member function it gets very messy:

```
class test {
    public:
        void testato(int i){
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    PermissionManager perm{};
    PermissionFunction<std::function<void(int)>>
permf{
      std::bind(&test::testato, this, std::placeholders::_1),
      std::bind(&test::testato, this, std::placeholders::_1),
      &perm, "hi"};
};
```

I am wondering if there is any way to shorten up the usage for the member variable types, I was thinking about using the template for that as well but I am not sure how to use std bind with veriadic template parameters and it has to work for any function type.

The goal would be to have the function declaration similar to the one with the std::functions in the example given, so that I can define the member object in this maner:

```
some_template<decltype(member_f)> 
wrapper_member{member_f, member_f, &tpm, "resource"}
```

Where member_f is an actual member function of a class. Ideally the type would be deduced but I think it would also be acceptable to repeat it in such manner:

```
some_template<return_t(args_t)>
wrapper_member{member_f, member_f, &tpm, "resource"}
```

Comment: you are already using lambdas in your first example, so why not also for member functions?

Comment: It would work with new code, that's true, but I wanted to make it straightforward to wrap the existing class with my library as well without going through the extra effort of writing the lambdas for everything.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean with "goign through the extra effort of writing the lambdas for everything. " what is "extra" about using lambdas? You need to register your callbacks somehow, using a lambda will not be much more to type than using `bind`, rather less

Comment: Firstly, I thought there might be method simplifying it so you can do somethink like: some_template<decltype(member_f)> wrapper_member{member_f, member_f, &tpm, "resource"} similar to what I am doing in the other case, but after having a look in lambdas this approach can work as well, I thought it is more effort than just calling member. I thought you need to similarly bind the this, but it looks like you can just capture it and it just works.

Comment: `some_template<decltype(member_f)> wrapper_member{member_f, member_f, &tpm, "resource"}` maybe add that to the question, because currently it is not 100% clear what is your aim from the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++20 introduces [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) which binds arguments only to the leading parameters, and so doesn't require the use of placeholder objects. It could be used to make your code more concise.

```
PermissionFunction<std::function<void(int)>> permf{
  std::bind_front(&test::testato, this),
  std::bind_front(&test::testato, this),
  &perm, "hi"};
```

A possible C++17 implementation:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename... Xs>
auto bind_front(F&& f, Xs&&... xs)
{
  return [
    f = std::forward<F>(f),
    xs = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Xs>(xs)...)](auto&&... ys) -> decltype(auto)
  {
    return std::apply(
      f,
      std::tuple_cat(xs, std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<decltype(ys)>(ys)...)));
  };
}
```

Comment: perhaps [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)?